# Размер видео

Tags: mediaplayer, видео, javascript

Всем привет, помогите плз!
Делал по этуму уроку - все работает!
http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=461

НО нужно что бы увеличивалось плеер при расширении!
Код видео

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=starladder1" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=starladder1&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object>

Ставиться в "content"

Подскажите как реализовать!

Comment: Изменение height="378" width="620" не помогает?

Comment: Объясню что есть:
есть сайт при нажатии можно увеличить контент центральный!
В нем находиться плеер!
Когда я жму расширить - хочу что бы плеер тоже менял размер

Comment: Пожалуйста приведите полный код страницы. Так не очень понятно в чем проблема. Код плеера тут почти не причем. кроме того, что вы явно задали ему размеры.